# limit the number of instance of a class

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

I want to put a limit on the number of instances you can make of a class.

I have the following code:

```
class A {
    static int cnt;
    int x;
    public:
    A() {
        cout<<"ctor called\n";
    }
    void* operator new(size_t size_in) {
        if(cnt<=10) {
            void *p=malloc(size_in);

            if(p==NULL) {
                throw bad_alloc();
            } else {
                cout<<"Memory allocation successful\n"; 
                ++cnt;
                return p;
            }
        } else {
            throw bad_alloc();
        }
    }
    ~A() {
        cout<<"Cleaning up the mess\n";
    }
};

int A::cnt=0;
int main() {
    A *a[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;++i) {
        try {
            a[i]=new A();
        } catch (bad_alloc &e) {
            cout<<"Error in allocating memory\n";
        }
    }
    try {
        A b;
    } catch (bad_alloc &e) {
        cout<<"Error in allocating memory on stack\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using a static counter and overloading the `new` operator I am able to put a limit on the number of objects that can be created on `Heap`.  I want to limit the number of instances created on `Stack` also.  One way is to make constructor private and provide a public API which first checks the counter and then returns accordingly.
Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Note that your solution will not work out too well in a multithreaded program.

Comment: Yes, I agree. As for now I have just focused on single threaded environment

Comment: Is your limit the total number of objects created, or the total number of objects at one time? Slightly different solutions for each.

Comment: If you don't hate Singleton, you can adapt it for preset number of instances.

Comment: @john total number of objects created, not at one time.To limit the number of objects in one go..i think i should keep a check on the size which i am requesting...Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @seccpur Yeah , I dont hate singleton.But i was just tryi ng to do this other way.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any other way of doing this??

You may just increase and check the counter in the constructor, the object will be destroyed if you throw an exception out of it. Furthermore, you won't have to distinguish between stack and heap.

Comment: Might want to note that increasing/checking the counter needs to happen in ALL constructors.   That means taking care to ensure all constructors do the check - which compiler-generated constructors do not.

Comment: Well, I thought of that.Throwing an exception will force the object the to be destroyed.But the point is,it will be created in the first place then because of exception thrown it will be destroyed. I want that it  should not be created even in the first place. Like it is happening in heap.

Comment: @aalisha What do you think the costs are to create an object on the stack? Allocating the memory merely means to increase the stack pointer, the whole cost lies in the constructor, which will be shortcut.

Comment: Yes , I know ESP will increase and then decrease.The crux is ,in case of heap sbrk(asuuming a simple implementation of malloc) will not be called if cnt >10 .But in case of stack we will construct(not allocate) and then destruct.

Comment: @aalisha: What's the deal with construction? All your constructor does is checking the counter value and eventually throw, one thing you would do anyways. I don't see your problem at all. For me, it rather looks like premature optimization. Have you measured the impact?

Comment: @ Jodocus I totally agree with you.I also had the same thoughts when I was asked this question. The main focus here is that we dont have toallocate memory in any case.As we all know construction happens after the memory being allocated, we have to somehow prevent allocation of memory. Frankly,speaking i havent measured the impact and i think i wont make any significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is to create helper template class and count objects using constructor and destructor:

```
class instance_limit_reached : public std::logic_error
{
public:
    using logic_error::logic_error;
};

template<typename T, int MaxInst>
class LimitInstances
{
    static std::atomic<int> instanceCount;

    void onNewInstance() {
        chekcTheLimit();
        ++instanceCount;
    }

    void chekcTheLimit() {
        if (instanceCount >= MaxInst)
            throw instance_limit_reached(std::string("Limit reached for ") + typeid(T).name());
    }

public:
    ~LimitInstances() {
        --instanceCount;
    }
    LimitInstances() {
        onNewInstance();
    }
    LimitInstances(const LimitInstances<T, MaxInst> &) {
        onNewInstance();
    }
    LimitInstances(LimitInstances<T, MaxInst> &&) {
        onNewInstance();
    }
};
```

Live [example with field use](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MJgw2aonUw42eloj) or [example with CRTP](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XdNC6FocdjREqQkB)

Now there is one important question, when object is moved do you consider this as a new instance (my example) or old instance (my code needs tweaking)?

Answer (score 1):

For fun, this is how I would do it: a CRTP design to be reusable with thread safe code:

```
template<class ToLimit,size_t MaxInstances>
class InstanceLimiter{
   static inline std::atomic<int> instances=0;
   private:
   static increase_count(){
      //memory order relaxed is sufficient because there is
      //only one modification order for each atomic objects.
      int actual=instances.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
      do{
        if (actual>=MaxInstances) throw some_error{};
      } while (instances.compare_exchange_weak(actual,actual+1,
                 std::memory_order_relaxed,std::memory_order_relaxed));
      }
    protected:
    //Provide definition for default constructor, copy constructor
    // and copy assignment operator so that defaulted derived special
    // member function behave as expected.
    InstanceLimiter(){increase_count();}

    InstanceLimiter(const InstanceLimiter&){increase_count();}

    InstanceLimiter& operator=(const InstanceLimiter&){
      increase_count();
      return *this;
      }

    ~InstanceLimiter(){
       instances.fetch_add(-1,std::memory_order_relaxed);
       }
    };

class A: InstanceLimiter<A,10> {
  int x;
  public:
  A() {
    //InstanceLimiter default constructor implicitly called
    cout<<"ctor called\n";
    }
  A(int x)
    //InstanceLimiter default constructor implicitly called here
    :x{x}{}
  //Implicitly declarer move/copy constructor/assignement implicitly calls
  // the copy constructor/assignment of InstanceLimiter
  ~A() {
      cout<<"Cleaning up the mess\n";
      //Default destructor of InstanceLimiter implicitly called here.
    }
  };
```

Last but not least: if you plan to use it in real code, consider to make your class A noexcept default and move constructible by providing it a default state that does not count as an instance.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to limit the number of instances created on Stack also

If you want different limits for Heap and Stack object, it seem to me that the cleaner way is the one of the private constructor with friend make functions (one for heap objects and one for stack object) with counters inside the make functions.

I mean... you can write `A` as follows

```
class A
 {
   private:
      int x;

      A (int x0 = 0)
       { std::cout << "ctor called" << std::endl; }

   public:
      ~A()
       { std::cout << "cleaning up the mess" << std::endl; }

      friend A * makeAinHeap (int);
      friend A makeAinStack (int);
 };
```

and the make-in-heap function is simply

```
A * makeAinHeap (int x)
 {
   constexpr auto maxAH { 3u };

   static auto ah { 0u };

   if ( ++ah > maxAH )
      throw std::runtime_error("no more A in Heap");

   return new A{x};
 }
```

and the analogous make-in-stack function is

```
A makeAinStack (int x)
 {
   constexpr auto maxAS { 2u };

   static auto as { 0u };

   if ( ++as > maxAS )
      throw std::runtime_error("no more A in Stack");

   return A{x};
 }
```

You can check all with the following `main()`

```
int main ()
 {
   auto p1 { makeAinHeap(0) }; // OK
   auto p2 { makeAinHeap(0) }; // OK
   auto p3 { makeAinHeap(0) }; // OK
   //auto p4 { makeAinHeap(0) }; // throw an exception

   auto s1 { makeAinStack(0) }; // OK
   auto s2 { makeAinStack(0) }; // OK
   //auto s3 { makeAinStack(0) }; // throw an exception

   delete p1;
   delete p2;
   delete p3;
 }
```